# connecting SQL Servers (2014) in workgroup in Windows 7

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, workgroup

I have a laptop (PC2) and a desktop (PC1) in a workgroup. PC1 is running SQL Server 2014 Developer and PC2 is running SQL Server Express 2014. Using SSMS, I have tried  many different ways to connect to PC1 Sql Server, but always get error 18456.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGXtT.png)

I'm obviously new to SQL Server administration. The servers on both PCs are configured for both Windows and SQL Server Authentication. SQL Server browser service is running and enabled. The log on ASUS-JHS-CM6850 (PC1, desktop) shows

> 06/05/2015 14:42:25,Logon,Unknown,Login failed for user
>   'ASUS-JHS-CM6850\Guest'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the
>   name provided. [CLIENT: 192.168.1.15] 06/05/2015
>   14:42:25,Logon,Unknown,Error: 18456 Severity: 14 State: 5.

I'm pretty sure I need to add logins or users to one or both servers, but I've been struggling with this for days now. I also don't know why it's logging in as Guest, nor have I found a way to change that.

Comment: Got my answer on SQL Server Central. Need to use SQL authorization. Everything is now working.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, should have posted as answer. See comment above. Problem solved.